# split String by space separated

Tags: java, string, parsing, split, word-spacing

I need to split words by space separated in java, so I have used `.split` function in-order to achieve that like as shown below

```
String keyword = "apple mango ";
String keywords [] = keyword .split(" ");
```

The above code is working fine but the only is that I sometimes my keyword will contain keyword like **"jack fruit"** , **"ice cream"** with double quotes like as shown below

```
String keyword = "apple mango \"jack fruit\" \"ice cream\"";
```

In this case I need to get 4 words like **apple**, **mango**, **jack fruit**, **ice cream** in keywords array

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: This might need regex to check for the quotes, just saying ;)

Comment: My general feeling is that this sort of problem might actually be suitable for a parser, rather than a single regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
String keyword = "apple mango \"jack fruit\" \"ice cream\"";

// first use a matcher to grab the quoted terms
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");      
Matcher m = p.matcher(keyword);
while (m.find()) {
    parts.add(m.group(1));
}

// then remove all quoted terms (quotes included)
keyword = keyword.replaceAll("\".*?\"", "")
                 .trim();

// finally split the remaining keywords on whitespace
if (keyword.replaceAll("\\s", "").length() > 0) {
    Collections.addAll(parts, keyword.split("\\s+"));
}

for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

**Output:**

```
jack fruit
ice cream
apple
mango
```

Comment: feedback appreciated :-)

Comment: Not working. You are missing jack fruit, because you only catch one group

Comment: @MuratK. My apologies, my matching regex had a slight problem, I originally answered this question on a cell phone.  It is working now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the keyword is `String keyword = "\"ice cream\" 192.168.214.125";` it is not giving the right result as `ice cream` and `192.168.214.125`

Comment: @AlexMan I added an extra `trim()` on the keyword to handle this edge case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks Tim

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If my keyword is `\"jack fruit\"` It is generates two keywords `jack fruit` and an empty string

Comment: @AlexMan I added another fix for this.  Just check to see if there are any remaining terms left to even split on.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it with a regex and two capturing group, one for each pattern. I'm not aware of any other way.

```
    String keyword = "apple mango \"jack fruit\" \"ice cream\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"?(\\w+\\W+\\w+)\"|(\\w+)");      
    Matcher m = p.matcher(keyword);
    while (m.find()) {
        String word = m.group(1) == null ? m.group(2) : m.group(1);
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

Comment: I removed my solution seeing this one, I don't know why I didn't thought about using two groups ...

Comment: While the OP has probably abandoned the thread, this solution is the most elegant one.

Comment: how about if somebody wrongly put only one double quotes at the last  like `apple mango"`

Comment: I'd think if you actually needs some more serious conditional parsing, you will have to pull out the heavy guns. Like JavaCC for example if you want to take this to the extreme and be able to detect this kind of error. The regex doesn't really have logic like that. If you throw in a wrench, it'll act funny.

Comment: @mprivat If the keyword is `String keyword = "\"ice cream\" 192.168.214.125";` it is not giving the right result as `ice cream` and `192.168.214.125`

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but i am sure that is not the best for performance / resources. It also works when you have fruits with more than two words. Feel free to edit or optimize my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String keyword = "apple mango \"jack fruit\" \"ice cream\" \"one two three\"";
        String[] split = custom_split(keyword);
        for (String s : split) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static String[] custom_split(String keyword) {
        String[] split = keyword.split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        boolean multiple = false;
        for (String s : split) {
            if (s.startsWith("\"")) {
                multiple = true;
                s = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
                temp.append(s);
                continue;
            }
            if (s.endsWith("\"")) {
                multiple = false;
                s = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
                temp.append(" ").append(s);
                list.add(temp.toString());
                temp = new StringBuilder();
                continue;
            }
            if (multiple) {
                temp.append(" ").append(s);
            } else {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        String[] result = new String[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `String.split()`.  You need to come up with a regular expression for the target tokens, and collect them through a matcher, like this:

```
    final Pattern token = Pattern.compile( "[^\"\\s]+|\"[^\"]*\"" );

    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = token.matcher( "apple mango \"jack fruit\" \"ice cream\"" );
    while( m.find() )
        tokens.add( m.group() );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split string on quotes, and then additionally split even members by spaces.

```
    String keyword = "apple mango \"jack fruit\" \"ice cream\"";
    String splitQuotes [] = keyword.split("\"");

    List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < splitQuotes.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            Collections.addAll(keywords, splitQuotes[i].split(" "));
        } else {
            keywords.add(splitQuotes[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Empty cell can be in keywords only if we have inside of quotes "". If you meant it will add them when two quotes are one after another (like for \"jack fruit\" \"ice cream\"), it will just call addAll and add empty String array, so it won't affect result.
Or there is some other scenario I'm not seeing?